# Trigger websocket error event 

Tags: error-handling, websocket

I am testing websocket and trying to find scenarios to trigger an error event on the client side. The protocol says

> If the user agent was required to fail the websocket connection or the WebSocket connection is closed with prejudice, fire a simple event named error at the WebSocket object.

However using this logic, I tried connecting to a server which does not support websocket. I see that browser is actually firing the "close" event but "error" event is not getting triggered.

Q : Should the above mentioned scenario fire an error event ? Also, what are the other scenarios with which I can possible trigger an error event on the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets specifications are not fully followed by all browsers.
So each implementation has own differences. For example Chrome wont throw onerror event on connection issues.
But FireFox does throw onerror whenever connection is broke by endpoint (disconnected from code, just turned off server, or even inability to connect).

So you can't really for now count on stability of this event implementations.
Based on my experience, I see for now that onerror event is pretty specific to browser, and has just a few logical scenarios in common.